# Clustering Using MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, pattern-matching, k-means

I have unstructured twitter data which is retrieved by the apache flume and stored it into the HDFS. So now I want to convert this unstructured data into structured one using the mapreduce.
Task wanted to do using the mapreduce:
1. conversion Unstructured to structure one.
2. I just want the text part which contain tweet part.
3. I want to identify the tweets for particular topic and grouped according to their sub part.
e.g. I have tweets of samsung handset so i want to make a group according to their handsets like groups of Samsung Note 4, Samsung galaxy etc.

It is my college project so my guide suggested me to use k means algorithm, I search a lot on k means but failed to understand how to identifies the Centroid for this basically i failed to understand how to apply K means to this situation in MapReduce.

Please gude me if I am doing wrong as I am new to this concept

Answer (score 0):

K-means is clustering algorithm. It cluster or group similar data and calculate the common centroid. You can create time-series for the above questions you have mention. Group the tweets according to the topic.

K-mean implementation in MapReduce.
https://github.com/himank/K-Means

Using K-means in Twitter datasets.

You can check the following links

> https://github.com/JulianHill/R-Tutorials/blob/master/r_twitter_cluster.r
>
> http://www.r-bloggers.com/cluster-your-twitter-data-with-r-and-k-means/
>
> http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5983_af66eca6775f4528a72b8e243a6ecf2d.html